# Giving Apache permission on Joomla folder

Tags: apache, joomla, chown

I have a Joomla site that the files is owner by root:root. But this way I can't update or install any plugins on Joomla. However when I set de folder's site to the apache owner the site downs return ERROR 500.
How could I fix it?

I've tried set apache owner end set the permissions like below:

`chown apache:apache /var/www/html/site`

`chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/site`

Ps.: The site was migrated from another server where the owner of the files is the apache.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `apachectl -S` as root or sudo (`sudo apachectl -S`) and look at the lines which tell User and Group owner.

Other solution, typing the command `ps faux` will tell you what you need at first column the owner of the process you want to know about.

Also, `htop` command could help you as same as before if it is installed.

EDIT :

you can also specify -R to do recursive with chown command

Comment: Running apachectl as root return: 

User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48

That looks like normal to me. But when I run chown -R apache:apache to site's folder the web site return HTTP ERROR 500.

There are another site in the same server, and it has apache as owner and work normally. I really don't know what could be. 

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. Was just the permissions on files the problem. I don't know why, but when I moved the files of site to another server the folders change the permissions 755 to 655. Changed this permissions everything cames back to normal.

Thanks again!